# Неправильный результат в select запросе с REGEXP и IF

Tags: mysql, регулярные-выражения

```
SELECT p.*, IF(p.PriceReductionCheck, p.PriceReductionRetail, '') as PriceReduction
  GROUP BY p.Id HAVING PriceReduction REGEXP '0.75' 
  ORDER BY p.Name;
```

Результат

```
Id PriceReduction
1
2 0.5
```

.

```
SELECT p.*, IF(p.PriceReductionCheck, p.PriceReductionRetail, '') as PriceReduction 
  GROUP BY p.Id HAVING PriceReductionRetail REGEXP '0.75' 
  ORDER BY p.Name;
```

Результат

```
Id PriceReduction
1 0.75
2 0.75
```

`PriceReduction** REGEXP '0.75'` вернул неправильный результат. Как исправить 1 запрос, чтобы он работал правильно по PriceReduction?

Запрос полностью

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS 0 AS isreadonly, p.*, IF(p.SpecialPriceCheck OR p.iscombo, CASE WHEN p.mmType = 'mixAndMatch' THEN 'Special: Mix & Match' WHEN p.mmType = 'priceModifier' THEN 'Special: Price Modifier' WHEN p.mmType = 'priceEachMix' THEN 'Special: Price Each Mix' ELSE '' END , '') as mType, IF(p.PriceReductionCheck, p.PriceReductionRetail, '') as PriceReduction, IF(p.NewPriceCheck, p.NewPriceRetail, '') as NewPrice, ( SELECT sum(pv.ReimburseRetail) FROM PromotionsVendors pv WHERE pv.PromotionId = p.Id AND pv.ReimburseCheck = 1 ) as Reimburse, ( SELECT pct.Date FROM PriceChangeTemp pct WHERE pct.Id = p.Id ) as LastSaleDate, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT pvAv.name SEPARATOR ', ') as ReimburseVendor FROM Promotions p LEFT JOIN PromotionsVendors pv ON pv.promotionid = p.id LEFT JOIN AccountVendors pvAv on pvAv.vendorid=pv.vendorid and pvAv.accountid = '46' WHERE p.AccountId='46' AND (p.indefenetly = 1 OR p.dateTo >= CURDATE()) AND ( p.Id!='') GROUP BY p.Id HAVING PriceReduction REGEXP '0.75' ORDER BY p.Name limit 0, 50
```

Comment: Вы бы исходные данные привели. Я например не понимаю зачем тут group by. Он же по полю ID, которое у вас наверное уникально или нет ?

Comment: Просто использование в предложении having любых условий, работающих не с результатами агрегирующих функций может приводить к любым чудесам и хотелось бы избавится от group by и проверять условия в where

Comment: И кстати, почему REGEXP, вы действительно хотите найти в строке (даже в середине) значение '0-любой_имвол-75' по крайней мере сейчас вы делаете именно это, потому как regexp ищет по всей строке и точка обозначает любой символ

Comment: https://screencloud.net/v/vj9b  , результат запроса без HAVING PriceReduction REGEXP '0.75', видно что 1 строка с 0.75 есть. А почему тогда по PriceReductionRetail работает корректно?

Comment: Я бы это в where перенес в виде `AND (p.PriceReductionCheck=0 OR p.PriceReductionRetail REGEXP '0.75')` только PriceReductionCheck поправьте как вам нужно, потому как я не понял какой там тип данных и как там false обозначен. ну и 10 раз подумал действительно ли там regexp

Comment: И, кстати, Reimburse можно вычислять не подзапросом а так: `sum(IF(pv.ReimburseCheck=1,pv.ReimburseRetail,NULL))` (pv у вас в запросе уже есть). Ну и до кучи LastSaleDate можно так же не подзапросом, а подклеить таблицу по left join к основной части и брать просто колонку от туда

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, попробую сделать как вы написали!!!

Comment: @Mike Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши комментарии в виде ответа.